# Search not working for some reason

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am trying to make my search look in my database for $searchtext where $selecteditem represents the columb it's searching. For some reason when I try searching something that I am positive exists, it returns 0 results.

Yes I know about the sql injections, I am going to change it to mysqli once I figure out how to easily do so.

My form-

```
<form name="search" id="search" method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="searchterm" id="searchterm">
    <select name="selectitem">
        <option value="propertydescription">Property/Description</option>
        <option value="transactiontype">Transaction type</option>
        <option value="applicabledocument">Applicable document</option>
        <option value="recieved">recieved</option>
        <option value="paid">paid</option>
    </select>

</div></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="search" value="search"></td>
```

My php for this-

```
if (isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $columbname = $_POST['selectitem'];
    $searchterm  = $_POST['searchterm'];
    $query="SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE agentclient  = '$agentclient' AND $columbname = '$searchterm'";
    $result = mysql_query ($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
else
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working where? What does your query look like, what does `$agentclient` contain?

Comment: In the `<form>` you have `action=""` - is that what you wanted?

Comment: $agentclient contains the name it is looking for, I have two queries, one shows just the results for $agentclient and this one should show the results for $agentclient $ the search term, which its not.

Comment: What does your full query look like?

Comment: Try echoing your SQL and running it through PHP MyAdmin - that will probably reveal the source of the problem.

Comment: Forming queries using unfiltered user input? Wonder what would happen if $searchterm suddenly contains "'); DELETE FROM agentclient; --"?

Comment: Your code is so insecure, read about **SQL INJECTION**

Comment: Yes I know its insecure. This is not going to be publicly shown. Select people will even have access to the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use LIKE operation if $columbname is varchar  or remove $ sign from columbname field

Answer (score 0):

You can test it by printing your query and checking that either it is passing the required parameters or not. If yes then copy the query and run the mysql db and check the results .

```
  if (isset($_POST['search']))
    {
        $columbname = $_POST['selectitem'];
        $searchterm  = $_POST['searchterm'];

    echo "SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE agentclient  = '$agentclient' AND $columbname = '$searchterm'"; exit;

        $query="SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE agentclient  = '$agentclient' AND $columbname = '$searchterm'";
        $result = mysql_query ($query) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    else
```